# ORA-01005 NullPassword: What does Oracle consider to be null?

Tags: java, jdbc, oracle11g

I have a piece of code along the following lines:

```
Properties props = new Properties();
props.put("user", user.getUserName());
props.put("password", user.getPassword());
//add more properties
//...
Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("url",props);
```

So, there is no way that I can see that a null password property can be passed into the connection.  Not only does `user.getPassword()` throw an exception if the password is `null`, setting a `null` value on `props` would throw an NPE.  Either of this will cause the call to `DriverManager.getConnection(..)` to be bypassed.  Yet on occasion, the connection attempt fails and Oracle returns an

> ORA-01005 ORA-01005: null password given; logon denied

The only way I can recreate this on demand is by commenting out the line that sets the password.  Otherwise I can't see how a `null` value is getting to Oracle.

Could it be that there are some values that Oracle reports to be `null` that are not strict Java `null`s?

I'm using `oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver` to connect to Oracle 11.2.0.3.0

Many thanks for any help!

Comment: Have you tried using an empty string?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why does Oracle 9i treat an empty string as NULL?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/203493/why-does-oracle-9i-treat-an-empty-string-as-null)

Comment: Try debugging your code using: System.out.println("user: >" + user.getUserName() + "<, password: >" + user.getPassword() + "<").  NULL in oracle means "no value", which includes empty strings.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the Oracle jdbc driver considers the empty string to be equivalent to NULL.

Answer (score 3):

Oracle database differs from Java in this sense. It treats String empty values as null.
See also [Oracle treating empty string as NULL problem for a Java / JPA programmer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5510509/671988)